# Optimized way to handle extremely large number without using external library

Tags: c, algorithm, math

**Optimized way to handle the value of n^n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^9)**

I used `long long int` but it's not good enough as the value might be (1000^1000)

Searched and found the `GMP library` http://gmplib.org/ and `BigInt class` but don't wanna use them. **I am looking for some numerical method to handle this.**

**I need to print the first and last *k* (1 ≤ k ≤ 9) digits of `n^n`**

For the first *k* digits I am getting it like shown below (it's bit ugly way of doing it)

```
num = pow(n,n);
while(num){
    arr[i++] = num%10;
    num /= 10;
    digit++;
}
while(digit > 0){
    j=digit;
    j--;
    if(count<k){
        printf("%lld",arr[j]);
        count++;
    }
    digit--;
}
```

and for last *k* digits am using `num % 10^k` like below.

```
findk=pow(10,k);
lastDigits = num % findk;
enter code here
```

**maximum value of k is 9. so i need only 18 digits at max.
I am think of getting those 18 digits without really solving the complete n^n expression.**

Any idea/suggestion??

Comment: Why don't you want to use a library? You're basically going to have to write something that duplicates their functionality, but without any of the testing or rigour.

Comment: If you must code a big integer library, you can make it simpler by not making it use dynamic allocation, and instead statically allocating an array large enough to hold the largest number you must calculate with. Then write algorithms for all the operations you need them to support by making them iteratively scale along the array for `length` entires in the array. After all, if that's all you need for your purposes, why write more? But the fact that you say OPTIMIZED implies you should not make a bigint library and just use a pre-existing one. :)

Comment: You won't simply have a thousand bits pseudo-basic type variable that you can operate with simple arithmetics and print with libc `printf()`. Single values bigger than 64-bit will require some code to be handled.

Comment: If `k` is reasonably sized you could find the least significant `k` digits using modular arithmetic without a special big integer library.

Comment: maximum value of k is 9. so i need only 18 digits at max. I am think of getting those 18 digits without really solving the complete n^n expression.
That's why i don't want to use a library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding the Least Significant Digits (last k digits) are easy because of the property of modular arithmetic, which says: `(n*n)%m == (n%m * n%m)%m`, so the code shown by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) which followed [exponentiation by squaring method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method) will work well for finding `k` LSDs.

Now, Most Significant Digits (1st k digits) of `N^N` can be found in this way:

```
 We know, 
 N^N = 10^(N log N)
```

So if you calculate `N log (N)` you will get a number of this format `xxxx.yyyy`, now we have to use this number as a power of 10, it is easily understandable that xxxx or integer part of the number will add xxxx zeros after 10, which is not important for you! That means, if you calculate `10^0.yyyy`, you will get those significants digits you are looking for. 
So the solution will be something like this:

```
double R = N * log10 (N);
R = R - (long long) R; //so taking only the fractional part
double V = pow(10, R);
int powerK = 1;
for (int i=0; i<k; i++) powerK *=10;
V *= powerK;
//Now Print the 1st K digits from V
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// note: Scope of use is limited.

#include <stdio.h>

long long powerMod(long long a, long long d, long long n){
// a ^ d mod n
    long long result = 1;
    while(d > 0){
        if(d & 1)
            result = result * a % n;
        a = (a * a) % n;
        d >>=1;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void){
    long long result = powerMod(999, 999, 1000000000);//999^999 mod 10^9
    printf("%lld\n", result);//499998999

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks BLUEPIXY, it's very elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use [bigint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigint) libraries?

bignum arithmetic is very hard to do right and efficiently. You could still get a PhD by working on that subject.

Fist, bigint arithmetic have non-trivial algorithmics

Then, bigint implementations usually need some machine instructions (like add with carry) which are not easily accessible in plain C.

For your specific problem (first and last few digits of *N<sup>N</sup>*) you'll better also reason on paper (using arithmetic theorems) to lower the complexity. I am not an expert, but I guess that still remains intractable, perhaps with a complexity worse than *O(N)*