# How to efficiently verify whether pow(a, b) % b == a in C (without overflow)

Tags: c, modulus, integer-overflow, memory-efficient

I'd like to verify whether

> pow(a, b) % b == a

is true in C, with 2 ≤ b ≤ 32768 (2<sup>15</sup>) and 2 ≤ a ≤ b with a and b being integers.

However, directly computing `pow(a, b) % b` with b being a large number, this will quickly cause C to overflow. What would be a trick/efficient way of verifying whether this condition holds?

This question is based on finding a witness for Fermat's little theorem, which states that if this condition is false, b is not prime.

Also, I am also limited in the time it may take, it can't be too slow (near or over 2 seconds). The biggest Carmichael number, a number `b` that's not prime but also doesn't satisfy `pow(a, b)% b  == a` with `2 <= a <= b` (with b <= 32768) is 29341. Thus the method for checking `pow(a, b) % b == a` with `2 <= a <= 29341` shouldn't be too slow.

Comment: By `a ^ b` you mean `a` raised to the power `b` or `bitwise XOR` of `a` and `b`?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya i thinks he means power because else it is much harder to get an overflow. However `^` in C is normally XOR, so pretty hard to say for sure.

Comment: @izlin I figured he meant power but I was asking just to clarify.

Comment: Look at the iterative square-and-multiply algorithm for a general way of computing the exponentiation modulo n. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). This can be even more efficient by using the k-ary- the improved k-ary or the sliding window method. Multiplications can be computed more efficiently when using the Karatsuba-Multiplication. Karatsuba + Sliding Window yields the fastest algorithm.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, I did, thanks! Fixed it now!

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt sorry I keep messing it up :]

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt you don't need to do the exponentiation as that would need a lot of time and memory for large powers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate (a^b)%c where 0<=a,b,c<=10^18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485750/calculate-abc-where-0-a-b-c-1018)

Comment: Post should clearly state `a,b` are integers.

Comment: the `pow()` function expects `double` for parameter types.  Not all integer values can be exactly represented via a `double`  so some integer values will not result in the same value after being run through this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating (a^b)%MOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272437/calculating-abmod)

Comment: [Raising large number to large power and mod it by a large number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27153665/995714), [Calculate (a^b)%c where 0<=a,b,c<=10^18](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32485750/995714), [Calculating (a^b)%MOD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11272437/995714), [a to power b modulus k](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30138020/995714)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) method.

The idea is the following:

- Decompose `b` in binary form and decompose the product
- Notice that we always use `%b` which is below 32768, so the result will always fit in a 32 bit number.

So the C code is:

```
/*
 * this function computes (num ** pow) % mod
 */
int pow_mod(int num, int pow, int mod)
{
    int res = 1

    while (pow>0)
    {
        if (pow & 1)
        {
            res = (res*num) % mod;
        }
        pow /= 2;
        num = (num*num)%mod;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: This works indeed! I had looked at this already but had difficulty implementing it, this seems to work! (but you forgot ; after res = 1 :). Thank you!

Comment: Apart from data types (`short` or `unsigned short`, for input parameters, return type and `res` datatype to `unsigned long int` or `long int`), this looks good. Maybe also braces around `res = (res*num) % mod`. +1.

Comment: Corner case failure: This `pow_mod(num, 0, 1)` --> 1 and should be 0.  Suggest change: `int res = 1%mod;`.  But then OP did say: 2 ≤ a ≤ b.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing modular arithmetic in Z/bZ.

Note that, in a quotient ring, the n-th power of the class of an element is the class of the n-th power of the element, so we have the following result:

```
(a^b) mod b = ((((a mod b) * a) mod b) * a) mod b [...] (b times)
```

So, you do not need a big integer library.

You can simply write a C program using the following algorithm (pseudo-code):

- declare your variables a and b as integers.
- use a temporary variable temp that is initialized with a.
- do a loop with b steps, and compute `(temp * a) mod b` at each step, to get the new temp value.
- compare the result with a.

With this formula, you can see that the highest value for temp is 32768, so you can choose an **integer** to store temp.

Comment: The number of iterations for this algorithm would be `b` multiplications, which is very bad. The square-and-multiply algorithm achieves a complexity of `log2(b)` squarings and `hammingWeight(b)` (also at max `log2(b)`) multiplications. When `b=32768` your algorithm needs `32768` iterations, whereas the simple SQ+MUL needs 15 iterations.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I wanted to show the **simplest** algorithm that achieve the main goal in the question: not having an overflow in C. Of course, this is not the fastest algorithm, as you said.

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo thank you, this indeed works! However, I am also limited in the time it may take; the biggest Carmichael number  (a number  b that's not prime but also doesn't satify pow(a,b)%b == a with 2<=a<=b) within the limit for b is 29341, and this method would then have to be repeated 29341 as well, being considerably slow.

Comment: "highest value for temp is 32767 ^ 2" --> I'd say the highest value for temp is `32768`.  The `(temp * a) mod b` needs to be done with about 2x wider math.

Comment: Yes your are right, I've patched my answer. Thanks.