# How to deal with 128bit variable in MinGM32 bit compiler for Encryption (Diffie Hellman Algorithm) in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, boost, bigint, diffie-hellman

I want to use the below equation in one of the code

### A = g^a mod p; //g raise to a modulus p.

(something like 2^5 % 3) = 32%3 = 2

(This equation looks like Diffie Hellman algorithm for security)

Where:

- ^ is (power)
- g is fixed number 0x05
- a is 128bit(16bytes) randomly generated number,
- p is fixed hex number of 128bit(16bytes). Something like (0x0xD4A283974897234CE908B3478387A3).

I am using:

- Qt 4.8.7
- Compiler MinGW32 (checked with boost library boost 1.70)

### The solutions which I found which didn`t work for me are listed below:

1. one can use __int128 but to support that one should have used
   latest GCC compiler or MinGW64 bit compiler, neither of that I am using now.
2. I found one latest version of Qt has QSslDiffieHellmanParameters class,
   but again not supported in our Qt version.
3. I found some libraries like  boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp (boost 1.70))
   that does have data type such as int128_t and int256_t, but due to 
   our compiler isssue or something else, we are not able to store
   128bit number, meaning
   if I do:

```
    int128_t ptval128 = 0xAB1232423243434343BAE3453345E34B;
    cout << "ptval128 = " << std::hex << ptval128 << endl;
    //will print only 0xAB12324232434343;//half digits only,
```

4. I tried using Bigint which much more useful, but again
   5^(128bit number) is way too big, it takes hours to compute things,
   (I waited till 1 hour  and 16 mins and kill the application).

```
    int myGval = 0x05;
    128_bit_data_type myPVal= 0xD4A283974897234CE908B3478387A3; 

    128_bit_data_type 128_bit_variable = 128_bit_random_data;
    myVal = (myGval)^(128_bit_variable) % (myPVal);
```

Comment: this is an [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282). You should ask how to calculate the modulo of a power instead. Possible duplicate of [Raising large number to large power and mod it by a large number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27153665/995714), [Calculate (a^b)%c where 0<=a,b,c<=10^18](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32485750/995714), [Calculating (a^b)%MOD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11272437/995714), [a to power b modulus k](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30138020/995714)... Besides, mingw is very bad compared to mingw64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how to do modular exponentiation! The first problem is that `5 ^ 128_bit_variable` is *huge*, so big that it won't fit into memory in any computers available today. To keep the required storage space within bounds, you have to take the remainder `% myPVal` after every operation.

The second problem is that you can't compute `5 ^ 128_bit_variable` simply by multiplying by `5` by itself `128_bit_variable` times -- that would take longer than the age of the universe. You need to use an exponentiation ladder, which requires just `128` squarings and at most `128` multiplications. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) for the details. In the end, the operation `5 ^ 128_bit_number` should take a fraction of a second.

Comment: that number far exceeds the total number of particles in the universe (~10⁸⁰)

Comment: @TonyK thank you so much for your comment. I checked your Wikipedia link, and followed https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exponential-squaring-fast-modulo-multiplication/ link, it seems working well, i changed data type from long int to Bigint.

Comment: Hi all, I found other solution to solve this equation using Crypto++ library,
Checkout the link https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html#a3b3f94c11fbf120d78837483093dfc8b